# LAG fucntion With Case/Rank Function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two messages('usb_port_reset','onewire_cable') in the column lbb_diag_value in a single table.

The two columns I am using are:
created_at(with timestamp),lbb_diag_value

Problem: I want to associate one_wire_cable for all the consecutive usb_port_reset messages until another one_wire_cable is found in the table.

For example:

```
         Created_at    lbb_diag_value
         1 PM          onewire_cable
         1:15 PM       usb_port_reset
         3:00 Pm       usb_port_reset
         12Pm          onewire_cable
         Some Time     usb_port_reset
```

Cuurent Solution: I am using the lag function and left join and this works fine if I don't have consecutive usb_port_reset messages.

Below is my code:

```
  WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT e2.identifier
        ,e2.created_at
        ,e2.model
        ,e2.sw_pkg_version
        ,e2.type
        ,e2.lbb_diag_value
        ,e2.lbb_diag_type
    FROM (
        SELECT e1.identifier
            ,e1.created_at
            ,e1.model
            ,e1.sw_pkg_version
            ,e1.lbb_diag_type
            ,e1.lbb_diag_value
            ,e1.type
        FROM eld_messages e1
        WHERE e1.type = 'lbb_diag'
            AND e1.lbb_diag_type = 'usb_port_reset'
            AND { % condition created_filter % } e1.created_at { % endcondition % }
        ) e2
    )
    ,onewire
AS (
    SELECT e2.identifier
        ,e2.lbb_diag_value
        ,e2.created_at
        ,e2.type
        ,e2.lbb_diag_type
        ,e2.prev_lbb_diag_type
        ,e2.prev_created_at
        ,e2.prev_lbb_diag_value
        ,e2.model
        ,e2.sw_pkg_version
        ,e2.seqnum
    FROM (
        SELECT e1.identifier
            ,e1.created_at
            ,e1.lbb_diag_value
            ,e1.type
            ,e1.lbb_diag_type
            ,e1.event_id
            ,e1.model
            ,e1.sw_pkg_version
            ,LAG(e1.lbb_diag_type) OVER (
                PARTITION BY e1.identifier ORDER BY e1.created_at
                    ,e1.event_id DESC
                ) AS prev_lbb_diag_type
            ,LAG(e1.created_at) OVER (
                PARTITION BY e1.identifier ORDER BY e1.created_at
                    ,e1.event_id DESC
                ) AS prev_created_at
            ,LAG(e1.lbb_diag_value) OVER (
                PARTITION BY e1.identifier ORDER BY e1.created_at
                    ,e1.event_id
                ) AS prev_lbb_diag_value
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY e1.lbb_diag_type ORDER BY e1.created_at
                    ,e1.event_id DESC
                ) seqnum
        FROM eld_messages e1
        WHERE e1.type = 'lbb_diag'
            AND e1.lbb_diag_type IN (
                'onewire_cable'
                ,'usb_port_reset'
                )
            AND { % condition created_filter % } e1.created_at { % endcondition % }
        ORDER BY e1.identifier
            ,e1.created_at
        ) e2
    WHERE (
            e2.lbb_diag_type = 'usb_port_reset'
            AND e2.prev_lbb_diag_type = 'onewire_cable'
            )
        OR (
            CASE 
                WHEN e2.lbb_diag_type = 'usb_port_reset'
                    AND e2.prev_lbb_diag_type = 'usb_port_reset'
                    THEN e2.seqnum = 1
                END
            )
    )
SELECT cte.identifier
    ,cte.created_at
    ,cte.model
    ,cte.sw_pkg_version
    ,cte.type
    ,cte.lbb_diag_type
    ,cte.lbb_diag_value
    ,onewire.prev_lbb_diag_value AS onewire_lbb_diag_value
    ,onewire.prev_created_at AS onewire_created_at
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN onewire ON cte.identifier = onewire.identifier
    AND cte.created_at = onewire.created_at;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it work to nest the sub-select with the lags and filter out records where there's not a change to the lbb_diag_value? I didn't try to understand the whole context of that huge query and if you need the other records, but lag can be a great way to detect boundaries which seems like what you need.

```
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT e1.identifier ,e1.created_at ,e1.lbb_diag_value ,e1.type ,e1.lbb_diag_type ,e1.event_id
            ,e1.model ,e1.sw_pkg_version
            ,LAG(e1.lbb_diag_type) OVER (PARTITION BY e1.identifier ORDER BY e1.created_at ,e1.event_id DESC) AS prev_lbb_diag_type
            ,LAG(e1.created_at) OVER ( PARTITION BY e1.identifier ORDER BY e1.created_at ,e1.event_id DESC) AS prev_created_at
            ,LAG(e1.lbb_diag_value) OVER ( PARTITION BY e1.identifier ORDER BY e1.created_at ,e1.event_id) AS prev_lbb_diag_value
            ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY e1.lbb_diag_type ORDER BY e1.created_at ,e1.event_id DESC) seqnum
        FROM eld_messages e1
        WHERE e1.type = 'lbb_diag' AND e1.lbb_diag_type IN ('onewire_cable' ,'usb_port_reset')
            AND { % condition created_filter % } e1.created_at { % endcondition % }
        ORDER BY e1.identifier, e1.created_at
    ) t
    WHERE lbb_diag_value != prev_lbb_diag_value
) e2
```

If you need all the records you could make that into two sub-selects with a join (the select you have left joined to a select that detects the transitions) where the transition (lbb_diag_value != prev_lbb_diag_value) ends up as a new column indicating records that flip from one value to the other.

Then identifying the 'onewire_cable' ones would be something like:

```
select * from (
...join...
) j where j.flip = 1 and j.lbb_diag_value = 'onewire_cable'
```